# How to filter results from SUM of sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I am trying to return the sum of a count from two columns joined together from two tables. I need it to return the results that are greater than 16. Using MSSQL.

I am expecting:

```
--------------------------------------
total_customers  |   album_title
-----------------|--------------------
17               |    "Blah Blah"
--------------------------------------
```

Without a HAVING clause, the query totals up the columns as I expect.

```
--------------------------------------
total_customers  |   album_title
-----------------|--------------------
17               |    "Blah Blah"
--------------------------------------
5                |   "another title"
--------------------------------------
3                |   "I'm a title"
--------------------------------------
```

When I try to add the HAVING clause using the Greater Than (>) sign it does not return any results.

```
--------------------------------------
total_customers  |   album_title
-------------------------------------
```

When I switch it to Less Than(<) it returns all results.

```
--------------------------------------
total_customers  |   album_title
-----------------|--------------------
17               |    "Blah Blah"
--------------------------------------
5                |   "another title"
--------------------------------------
3                |   "I'm a title"
--------------------------------------
```

My Code:

```
SELECT SUM(total_customers) as total_customers, album_title
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer.id) as total_customers , album.album_title
FROM album
INNER JOIN customer ON album.album_id = customer.album_id
GROUP BY customer.id, album_title
) s
GROUP BY total_customers, album_title
HAVING total_customers > 16;
```

Comment: Your data model seems a bit off. A table called `customers` should contain customer data, e.g. a name, an address maybe, and perhaps a customer number. A table called `album` should contain album data, e.g. a title and a price. Then there should be a third table for orders showing which customer bought which album. In your model it seems the `customers` table is the order table actually, containing album ID and customer ID. The table contains a column called ID, but you count it distinctly, because you expect duplicates? A column called `ID` should uniquely identify a row in its table.

Comment: I am expecting duplicates. This is actually a homework problem that has the model set up like this, and I changed the table column names so I wouldn't give away the answer. That might have made reading this a little confusing. If I left DISTINCT out it will give me the wrong answer. The answer below solved my problem. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Describing what you want using English to repeat some of the operators that you use in your wrong code is not helpful. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Yes, table and column name customers.id do make this a bit confusing :-) It looks like this should suffice: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as total_customers, a.album_title
FROM album a INNER JOIN customer c ON c.album_id = a.album_id GROUP BY a.album_title HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) > 16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use aggregate function with `having` as following. The reason is `having` clause will execute first before `select` and after `group by`.

I have removed `total_customers` from `group by`.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(total_customers) as total_customers, 
    album_title
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as total_customers , 
        a.album_title
    FROM album a
    INNER JOIN customer c
    ON a.album_id = c.album_id
    GROUP BY c.id, album_title
) s
GROUP BY 
    album_title
HAVING SUM(total_customers) > 16;
```